# What can i use for marking events?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp net Web form , and i need to make notes when button clicked . 
I need to know what button was clicked last when i save information.
For example - someone click button "Create new entry" - i will make `static bool newflag` `= true` .I case of deleting -  `static bool delflag` will be `= true`.

But i need to control it in all program - when it true or when it false , and when i have about 4 flags , it is difficult .
Maybe someone know another way how can i make it ?
C# ASP.NET Web Form

Comment: `static` is a bad idea in ASP.NET. All your users will share the same flag, if one clicks "delete" it is being marked as "deleting" for every other user too. Instead you can use the `Session`.

Comment: Is hard to understand your question, you should organize it better.

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов Having an ID in the URL won't make that static variable unique to each user.

Comment: @TimSchmelter . Will session save information when i reload page ?

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов: yes, it is stored in server memory per user base so will survive page lifecycles

Comment: @TimSchmelter and if i want to use variables for multiply methods - its `Session` too?

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов: i dont know what that means but you can store anything in session

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, but why you delete your answer?

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов: you needed? I thought it would be too much. Of course you can have it easier and more concise, i just wanted to show that you can store everything in session in a readable way. Undeleted. Btw, you can also encapsulate the session handling in `UserEntryFlags`, so a property which stores or reads it in the session, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` is a bad idea in ASP.NET. All your users will share the same flag, if one clicks "delete" it is being marked as "deleting" for every other user too. Instead you can use the Session. If you want to store multiple informations readable and maintainable in a special type made for this purpose, here is a custom class with a dictionary and a custom enum as key.

The enum for the key:

```
public enum EntryEventType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    NewEntry = 1,
    DeletedEntry = 2, 
    // ....
}
```

A class to encapsulate the event-info and it's state and last-updated information:

```
public class EntryEvent
{
    public EntryEvent(EntryEventType type)
    {
        EventType = type;
    }
    public EntryEventType EventType { get; set; }
    public bool? Flag { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? LastChanged { get; private set; }

    public static EntryEvent GetTrue(EntryEventType type)
    {
        var e = new EntryEvent(type);
        e.SetFlag(true);
        return e;
    }

    public static EntryEvent GetFalse(EntryEventType type)
    {
        var e = new EntryEvent(type);
        e.SetFlag(false);
        return e;
    }

    public void SetFlag(bool flag)
    {
        Flag = flag;
        LastChanged = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

A class that encapsulates a dictionary to store informations for each event type:

```
public class UserEntryFlags
{
    private readonly Dictionary<EntryEventType, EntryEvent> UserEntryFlagDict = new Dictionary<EntryEventType, EntryEvent>();

    public UserEntryFlags()
    {
        UserEntryFlagDict.Add(EntryEventType.NewEntry, new EntryEvent(EntryEventType.NewEntry));
        UserEntryFlagDict.Add(EntryEventType.DeletedEntry, null);
        // ...
    }

    public EntryEvent this[EntryEventType type]
    {
        get
        {
            return UserEntryFlagDict[type];
        }
        set
        {
            UserEntryFlagDict[type] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of this class can be stored in the session:

```
protected void CreateNewEntry(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entryFlags = Session["UserEntryFlags"] as UserEntryFlags;
    if (entryFlags == null) entryFlags = new UserEntryFlags();
    entryFlags[EntryEventType.NewEntry] = EntryEvent.GetTrue(EntryEventType.NewEntry);
    Session["UserEntryFlags"] = entryFlags;
}
protected void DeleteNewEntry(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entryFlags = Session["UserEntryFlags"] as UserEntryFlags;
    if (entryFlags == null) entryFlags = new UserEntryFlags();
    entryFlags[EntryEventType.DeletedEntry] = EntryEvent.GetTrue(EntryEventType.DeletedEntry);
    Session["UserEntryFlags"] = entryFlags;
}
```